# Issue using APIgee as API gateway calling WCF RESTful service

Tags: wcf, iis-6, reverse-proxy, apigee, wso2-cloud

I have WCF RESTful services running on IIS6. (public exposed on internet)

example
http://{domain}:8000/todoService.svc/countPerLabel?uMID={uMID}&userID={userID}

I have setup APIGEE proxy API manager gateway to call the the WCF services.

http://{APIGEE}/v1/todo/countperlabel?uMID={uMID}&userID={userID}

Case A. When i call the APIGEE url for the first time it works - but when i make another call it delays for few seconds and response with timeout/service unavailable.

If i wait for about 10 minutes and calls the service again Case A occurs.

I am not able to understand - if i call my service url independently without APIgee everything works well.

I don't not want to give third party developer access to naked API url therefore like to secure it using either APIgee or WSO2.

Is it something to do with proxy issues where my IIS6 not able to respond back to request from proxy server?

Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the trace tool to examine the target request and response?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are having multiple endpoints. First call goes to one endpoint and the second to another one. Why dont you try a third call as well. If it works and the fourth one fails, then my explanation is correct. If it is the case, one of your endpoints may be having firewall issues.